# Fire appendTo() only once when document is ready (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, events, append, prepend

I want to remove the dynamically created "onsale" button when the page loads and put it a bit more up in the DOM.

But since there are 3 Elements that has this class he is firing it 3 times for each element and adds 3 "onsale" buttons to each position.

I tried to bind it to the one() handler of jQuery and switched between some events like click, load, ready, etc. Nothing was changing at all.

Also tried to a counter or just count the elements via length() but same as before.

**Heres my code:**

```
$('.onsale').one('click', function () { 

    $('.onsale').appendTo('.woocommerce-loop-product__title');
    console.log('fired!');
});
```

**Element that should move:**

```
<span class="onsale">Angebot!</span>
```

See live test environment here(scroll down to the bottom): [Link](http://www.matelade.de/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind only the first element using the selector:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
   $('.onsale:first').appendTo('.woocommerce-loop-product__title');
});
```

Comment: that does the same. Putting in 3 of the sales buttons. take a look at the live example.

Comment: You can use `$( document ).ready()` or `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` in jQuery, refer to the documentation on the link to understand what suits your requirement: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/